# What's wrong with this linqTOsql self referencing object mapping?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm trying to create a self referencing object using linqTOsql mapping. So far, I am definitely in over my head. Here's the code I have:

```
[Table]
public class Category
{
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey=true, IsDbGenerated=true, AutoSync=AutoSync.OnInsert)]
    public Int64 catID { get; set; }
    public Int64 parentCatID { get; set; }
    public string catName { get; set; }
    public string catDescription { get; set; }

    internal EntityRef<IEnumerable<Category>> _category;
    [Association(ThisKey = "parentCatID", Storage = "_category")]
    public IEnumerable<Category> category {
        get { return _category.Entity; }
        set { _category.Entity = value; }
    }
}
```

My `fakeRepository` is defined like this:

```
// Fake hardcoded list of categories
private static IQueryable<Category> fakeCategories = new List<Category> {
    new Category { catID = 1, parentCatID = 0, catName = "Root", catDescription = "" },
    new Category { catID = 2, parentCatID = 1, catName = "Category w/subs", catDescription = "" },
    new Category { catID = 3, parentCatID = 1, catName = "Category no subs but now has subs", catDescription = "" },
    new Category { catID = 4, parentCatID = 2, catName = "Zub Cat", catDescription = "" },
    new Category { catID = 5, parentCatID = 2, catName = "Sub Cat", catDescription = "" },
    new Category { catID = 6, parentCatID = 0, catName = "Another Root", catDescription = "" },
    new Category { catID = 7, parentCatID = 0, catName = "Ze German Root", catDescription = "" },
    new Category { catID = 8, parentCatID = 3, catName = "Brand new cats", catDescription = "" },
    new Category { catID = 9, parentCatID = 8, catName = "Brand new cats sub", catDescription = "" },
}.AsQueryable();
```

I pass `Category` to the view like this:

```
public ActionResult CategoryTree()
{
    IQueryable<Category> cats = genesisRepository.Category
                                                 .Where(x => x.parentCatID == 0)
                                                 .OrderBy(x => x.catName);
    return View(cats);
}
```

The problem that I'm running into is that all of this compiles, but I don't get anything beyond the root categories. `Model[0].category` is returning null.

What is wrong with my self-referencing object?

### Edit

I wonder if it's not working because I don't have a real linq-to-sql data context in my `fakeRepository`. If that's the case, is there a way around that? Can I can get this to work without a connection to a database?

Comment: Is my question that rediculous? Does anyone have any suggestions for how to improve my question or my approach in order to get an answer or solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, you hit the nail on the head. It's not working because you're using a fake repository.

Linq-to-Sql does all the wiring up for you and sets the related collections based on the properties (& their attributes) that you setup in your model.

I don't know how to accomplish this without a connection to the database because `internal EntityRef<IEnumerable<Category>> _category;` is completely foreign to me - I'm more of a POCO model type of guy.

After a quick google, I found this - [How to: Map Database Relationships (LINQ to SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386950.aspx)

Could you change your model to read:

```
[Column(IsPrimaryKey=true, IsDbGenerated=true, AutoSync=AutoSync.OnInsert)]
public Int64 CatId { get; set; }
[Column]
public Int64 ParentCatId { get; set; }
[Column]
public string CatName { get; set; }
[Column]
public string CatDescription { get; set; }

private EntitySet<Category> _ChildCategories;
[Association(Storage = "_ChildCategories", OtherKey = "ParentCatId")]
public EntitySet<Category> ChildCategories
{
    get { return this._ChildCategories; }
    set { this._ChildCategories.Assign(value); }
}

private EntityRef<Category> _ParentCategory;
[Association(Storage = "_ParentCategory", ThisKey = "ParentCatId")]
public Category ParentCategory
{
    get { return this._ParentCategory.Entity; }
    set { this._ParentCategory.Entity = value; }
}
```

Now because your `ChildCategories` is of type `EntitySet<Category>` (which inherits from `IList<T>`) you should be able to wire fake relationships up yourself.

So you could do something like this:

```
private static IQueryable<Category> GetFakeCategories()
{
    var categories = new List<Category> {
        new Category { CatId = 1, ParentCatId = 0, CatName = "Root", CatDescription = "" },
        new Category { CatId = 2, ParentCatId = 1, CatName = "Category w/subs", CatDescription = "" },
        //Blah
        new Category { CatId = 8, ParentCatId = 3, CatName = "Brand new cats", CatDescription = "" },
        new Category { CatId = 9, ParentCatId = 8, CatName = "Brand new cats sub", CatDescription = "" }
    };

    //Loop over the categories to fake the relationships
    foreach (var category in categories)
    {
        category.ChildCategories = new EntitySet<Category>(); //new up the collection
        foreach (var subLoopCategory in categories)
        {
            if (category.ParentCatId == subLoopCategory.CatId)
                category.ParentCategory = subLoopCategory;

            if (category.Id == subLoopCategory.ParentCatId)
                category.ChildCategories.Add(subLoopCategory);
        }
    }
    return categoies.AsQueryable();
}
```

It works in my head at least... :-)

HTHs,
Charles

**EDIT:** Re: Comment below about a null reference on `_childCategories`.

You could change the model to look like:

```
private EntitySet<Category> _ChildCategories = new EntitySet<Category>();
```

Comment: Ah, This acutally looks really promising. I'll try it out and get back to ya soon. Thanks for the effort!!!

Comment: I've been working on a different area of this project lately, I hope to revisit this soon to try out this solutions... btw: that MSDN article you foubnd was great. I must have been using the complete wrong search terms when I was looking.

Comment: I tried it and it seemed to be going great. It compiles. I got a warning that said: `Field 'Genesis.Domain.Entities.Category._childCategories' is never assigned to, and will always have its default value null`. Then when I tried to run the application I got an error in the browser that said: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` and the line that was erroring is here `set { this._childCategories.Assign(value); }`..... Any thoughts?

Comment: Sahweet!!! It seems to be working! This is sweet. I have been trying to figure this out for the longest time! BTW: I read you blog article about DateTime getting screwed up in MVC2beta GET requests because of Culture. I just wanna say... No one says "I was born fifteenth January." They always say "January fifteenth". :-) Thanks for the help with the code!

Comment: Oh and BTW: To get this object working in a view I needed to add `<add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>` to my web.config.

Comment: I could easily get into a religious debate about how mm/dd/yyyy is wrong and dd/mm/yyyy is right, but this is not the place for such a debate! ;-) Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

It is supposed to be null.  You are getting all categories where the ParentId = 0 ... and you don't have a child with an Id of 0.  So that seems right to me.

It is not showing any subcategories because it has no subcategories to show.  Try this:

```
    IQueryable<Category> cats = genesisRepository.Category
                                                 .Where(x => x.parentCatID != 0)
                                                 .OrderBy(x => x.catName);
```

The parentCatId needs to point to a valid CatId for it to be a subcategory.  This query should get you all the categories that are subcategories.

Comment: Same result with `parentCatID` set to null. It doesn't instantiate the sub categories.